# print javascript switch statement to html page

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Sorry if i am explaining this wrong, I am very new to javascript. I am trying to print this switch statement to my html page and i am not sure how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

On my HTML page I have:

```
<button type="button" onclick="weatherAssessment()">Weather Assassment</button>
<p id="result"> <p>
```

I am just not sure how to use getElementbyID to print the result to the page.

JavaScript:

```
function weatherAssessment(){

var currentDate = new Date();
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();

switch(currentMonth) {

    case 11:
    case 0:
    case 1:
        analysis = "It is chilly winter.";
        break;

    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        analysis = "A beautiful spring.";
        break;

    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
        analysis = "The heat of summer.";
        break;

    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
        analysis = "Fabulous Fall";
        break;

}

console.log(currentMonth);
console.log(analysis);

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to put the contents of the variable `analysis` onto some HTML element, and have an ID for it you could use in `getElementbyID`?

Comment: "print this switch statement"??? You mean you want to show the value of `analysis` on a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

  <button type="button" onclick="weatherAssessment()">Weather Assassment</button>
  <p id="result"> <p> 


</body>
</html>

<script>

  function weatherAssessment(){

    var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();

    switch(currentMonth) {

        case 11:
        case 0:
        case 1:
            analysis = "It is chilly winter.";
            break;

        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            analysis = "A beautiful spring.";
            break;

        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
            analysis = "The heat of summer.";
            break;

        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10:
            analysis = "Fabulous Fall";
            break;

    }

    // console.log(currentMonth);
    // console.log(analysis);

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Current Month: " + currentMonth + " Analysis: " + analysis;

  }

</script>
```

Comment: @Wil pleasure friend, if any of the posts helped you in answering your question please mark those ones as the answers and accept any editing changes to help viewers understand the question and answers better! :) all the best!

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "yourText";
```